# How can I commit all of my android studio projects to Github?

Tags: android, github, android-studio, version-control

I am going to install new windows. I want to push all of my android projects to Github. I know, how we can push one by one. But, is there any way by which we can push all of our projects simultaneously?

Comment: you must always commit one by one.

Comment: @Nilanchala I have a lot of projects, I was looking  for a shorcut.

Comment: You can use some other git client such as GitHub client or SourceTree or from terminal.